# Comparing column values of two dataframes and increment count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, like
df1=

```
Hair  Feathers  Eggs  Type
 0       0       0     1
 1       0       0     1
 0       1       0     2
 0       1       1     2
 0       0       1     6
```

and df2=

```
Hair  Feathers  Eggs  Count
 0       0       0     
 1       0       0     
 1       0       1
```

How can I compare the first row of df2 with all the rows of df1 in such a way that if df2.Hair is equal to df1.Hair value then the Count value should be updated by incrementing it by 1. And, similarly for second row of df2 and so on.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
The resultant output should look like this, it is only for the first row of df2

```
Hair  Feathers  Eggs  Type  Count
 0       0       0     1      1
 0       0       0     2      2
 0       0       0     6      1
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output?

Comment: @user3483203 I have edited the question to add the resultant output

Comment: Why are `Feathers,  Eggs` columns filled by `0` in output data for first row?

Comment: @eshfaqahmad could you explain why is the count `1,2,1` also why are the other columns 0? sorry i fail to understand. :)

Comment: Do you also intend to include a groupby on the 'Type' column? It is count `Hair == 0` count on each unique Type?

Comment: @anky_91 the count 1,2,1 is because for Hair=0, type=1 the count is 1, then for Hair=0, Type=2, Count=2 and for Hair=0, Type=1, the count is 1. Lastly, I don;t care about the other attributes (Feathers, eggs) either they are 0 or 1, but the df1.Hair must be equal to df2.Hair. Yes, surely I have not mentioned the groupby in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (df1.groupby(['Hair', 'Type']).size().reset_index(name='count'))
   Hair  Type  count
0     0     1      1
1     0     2      2
2     0     6      1
3     1     1      1

#if need default inner join
df3 = df2.merge(df1.groupby(['Hair', 'Type']).size().reset_index(name='count'), on='Hair')
#if need right join
#df3 = (df2.merge(df1.groupby(['Hair', 'Type']).size().reset_index(name='count'), 
#                  on='Hair', how='right'))
print (df3)

   Hair  Feathers  Eggs  Type  count
0     0         0     0     1      1
1     0         0     0     2      2
2     0         0     0     6      1
3     1         0     0     1      1
4     1         0     1     1      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does what I wanted to do, but is there a way to add the other two columns with the df3 that you calculated. Actually, df1 is the output of my model after training and df2 is the test data on which I want to find accuracy of my model. So any method/tips that can find the accuracy on my model will be really appreciated

Comment: @eshfaqahmad - hmmm, what are values in these columns? All `0` ? Or there si some another logic?

Comment: the values are the same as in the columns of feathers and eggs. 0's and 1's

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `groupby` and count to get the relevant counts and then a `merge` to get the right values into the result dataframe. E.g:

```
data1 = {'Hair': [0,1,0,0,0],
'Feathers': [0,0,1,1,0],
'Eggs': [0,0,0,1,1],
'Type': [1,1,2,2,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Hair': [0,1,1],
'Feathers': [0,0,0],
'Eggs': [0,0,1]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_counts = df.groupby(['Hair', 'Type']).agg('count')[['Feathers']].reset_index()
df_counts.rename(columns={'Feathers': 'Count'}, inplace=True)
pd.merge(df2, df_counts, how='outer', on='Hair')
```

Comment: My apologies, just seen your edit to include the expected output so believe I mis-understood the question... Taking another look now.

Comment: it does work quite nicely, but there are duplicated results in the output. 
Edit: There are no duplicates, I just realized

Comment: Sure :). Yeah I originally thought there were duplicates too but I was just missing the unique 'eggs' identifier in df2.